# Change table in to view - table use date function

Tags: mysql

i have MySQL query for adding data data add in to reg_data table and session=morning, that query is run.......for run this query data should be add to table in every day regularly....due to use of current date function. but if i change it to view that query is not run well. this is my original code

```
create  into velocity (date,run,velocity) 
select
  DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY),
  ((select anem_reading from reg_data where date=CURDATE() and session='morning')-(select anem_reading from reg_data where date=DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY)  and session='morning')) as run ,
  round((((select   anem_reading from reg_data where date=CURDATE() and session='morning')-(select anem_reading from reg_data where date= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY) and session='morning')) /24 ),1) as velocity
from reg_data
where
  session='morning'
  and date=CURDATE();
```

i change it create view

```
create  view velocity as (date,run,velocity)
select
  DATE_SUB(DATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY),
  ((select anem_reading from reg_data where date=DATE() and session='morning')-(select anem_reading from reg_data where date=DATE_SUB(DATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY) and session='morning')) as run ,
  round((((select   anem_reading from reg_data where date=DATE() and session='morning')-(select anem_reading from reg_data where date= DATE_SUB(DATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY) and session='morning')) /24 ),1) as velocity
from reg_data
where
  session='morning'
  and date=DATE();
```

can you help me this query is not run well i want to run this view from existing data of reg_data table not using current day option.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Take a minute to edit your question to make the code readable.  In the edit toolbar, highlight a code block and click `{}` or press `ctl-k` to format it as a code block (4-space indentation with a blank line before) We'll often edit for you, but there's a lot to pull out here and it would be better if you organize the linebreaks yourself.

Comment: The backtick notation is used for inline code only, and doesn't work well for multi-line code snippets.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski thanks dear for your instruction i'm new comer please help me

Comment: I've formatted the code blocks. Please review them and make sure I got the linebreaks sensibly.

Comment: your first query is strange, it's not selecting anything from the outer reg_data, i think you can delete that. Your second query looks like you'll get syntax error from trying to call `DATE()` without a parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this and see if it's a view that you want to show all date,run,velocity for each day

```
create  view velocity as 
select
  DATE_SUB(r.date,INTERVAL 1 DAY) as date,
  ((select anem_reading from reg_data where date=r.date and session='morning')-(select anem_reading from reg_data where date=DATE_SUB(r.date,INTERVAL 1 DAY)  and session='morning')) as run ,
  round((((select   anem_reading from reg_data where date=r.date and session='morning')-(select anem_reading from reg_data where date= DATE_SUB(r.date,INTERVAL 1 DAY) and session='morning')) /24 ),1) as velocity
from reg_data r
  WHERE session='morning';
```

here's the [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/29029/1/0)